# entity framework won't import my firebird stored procedure

Tags: .net, entity-framework, firebird

I am using EF for .NET 4 and the firebird .NET provider 3.0.2.0 with Firebird 2.5.

I have created a stored procedure as follows (DDL from IBEXPERT):-

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure GETNEWROWID
returns (
    ROWID ROWID)
as
begin
  /* Procedure Text */
  rowid = (select gen_uuid() from rdb$database);
  suspend;
end
^ 

SET TERM ; ^

/* Existing privileges on this procedure */

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE GETNEWROWID TO SYSDBA;
```

When I try and update my model, the SP is listed but when I select it, it does not get added to the model. There is no trace of it.

I have tried to add it as a function import but it does not appear in the dropdown list.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Try to remove the `SUSPEND`, there is a difference between selectable and 'executable' stored procedures; maybe it matters.

Comment: Have you checked that it should automatically import the SP into model?

Comment: Mark: I removed the suspend but it made no difference.

Comment: Cincura - I don't understand what you are asking. Surely the SP should be imported if I have selected it from the 'Update model from database' option.