# Using EF Designer from Database doesn't bring stored procedure (EF 6 and Firebird)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, firebird, edmx

After playing around with getting data from a Firebird database into a JSON web service (I originally posted this: [Connecting Firebird to an ASP.net WebAPI Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370825/connecting-firebird-to-an-asp-net-webapi-project)), I decided that I would try to work with stored procedures in Firebird.

I saw that I was able to use the EF Designer from database wizard to select Tables, Views, and Stored Procedures so I specifically added one table (Users, which is a list of user names and passwords) and one stored procedure (called Login, which basically takes a username and a password and confirms if the two inputs exist in one row in the Users table).

However, after selecting those two objects through the wizard, browsing the EDMX file under Model Browser (in this case USER.edmx) shows the table under Model.Store but **not** the Stored Procedure. I do see details about my stored procedure under Function Imports (the function Login with the two inputs) and under Complex Types (LOGIN_Result, with the one string output).

I figured not seeing the stored procedure listed under stored procedure in the Model.Store was not an issue so I continued on to create a Controller for that Model (using Web API2 Controller with actions, using EF).

From there, I was able to select my LOGIN_Result under Model class, and it's corresponding Data Context class. However, at this point I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Project.Models.LOGIN_Result'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> LOGIN_result: EntityType 'LOGIN_Result' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> LOGIN_Result: EntityType: EntitySet 'LOGIN_Result' is based on type 'LOGIN_Result' that has no keys defined.

At this point, I'm at a loss because I'm just looking to return a simple string (success or failure) depending on the input of the stored procedure. I don't understand why there's a requirement for a key from a stored procedure.

I've seen this error a few times (including on cincuras site here http://blog.cincura.net/233254-hunting-entitytype-image-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype-problem/) but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to get past this message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Again, I am a beginner so if I'm going about this with the wrong methodology or technology, let me know. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: I see the same behaviour here but no answer :( [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301877/entity-framework-wont-import-my-firebird-stored-procedure

Comment: I posted this [link]http://forums.asp.net/t/2043938.aspx?Entity+Framework+6+and+using+ADO+NET+Entity+Data+Model+doesn+t+bring+over+Firebird+Stored+Procedure on the forums at ASP.net (and will be posting it shortly on an appropriate FB forum) but basically, I debugged the process of adding a stored procedure through the Entity Framework Designer. Still can't bring over a stored procedure but I'm going to try making a simple stored procedure and see if that too fails.